# Making multiple keyboard events play and stop multiple songs

Tags: flash

I have been working on an flash music player and am using autoscript3. I have got the mouse clicks playing and stopping the songs fine, but have run into a problem when I try to assign keyboard events to play and stop multiple songs at once. What's happening is that on the first keyboard event it'll play the song and I hit it again it'll turn off the song (good that's what I want. The problem is though, if I hit the first keyboard event `(192) and then hit the second keyboard event q(81), then try to turn off the first keyboard event '(192) it actually ends up playing mySound2 again instead of turning it off. I believe this is because the keyboard events are on the stage and not individual buttons, like the MouseEvents are. Could someone help me fix the code below:

```
//mouse events
//button 2

var played2:Boolean=false;


var mySound2:Sound = new DontSpeak();
var myChannel2:SoundChannel = new SoundChannel();
BlueButton2.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,togglePlay2);


function togglePlay2(event:MouseEvent):void
{
  (!played2)?played2 = true : played2 = false;
  (played2)?myChannel2 = mySound2.play(0,100) : myChannel2.stop();
  (played2)?BlueButton2.gotoAndStop(2) : BlueButton2.gotoAndStop(1)

  myChannel2.addEventListener(Event.SOUND_COMPLETE,soundCompleted2);
}
function soundCompleted2(event:Event):void {
  played2 = false;
  BlueButton2.gotoAndStop(1);
}

//button 3


var played3:Boolean=false;


var mySound3:Sound = new Chances();
var myChannel3:SoundChannel = new SoundChannel();
BlueButton3.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,togglePlay3);


function togglePlay3(event:MouseEvent):void
{
  (!played3)?played3 = true : played3 = false;
  (played3)?myChannel3 = mySound3.play() : myChannel3.stop();
  (played3)?BlueButton3.gotoAndStop(2) : BlueButton3.gotoAndStop(1)

  myChannel3.addEventListener(Event.SOUND_COMPLETE,soundCompleted3);
}
function soundCompleted3(event:Event):void {
  played3 = false;
  BlueButton3.gotoAndStop(1);
}


//Keyboard events

stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN,keydown);

function keydown(event:KeyboardEvent):void
{
  if (event.keyCode==192)
  (!played2)?played2 = true : played2 = false;
  (played2)?myChannel2 = mySound2.play(0,100) : myChannel2.stop();
  (played2)?BlueButton2.gotoAndStop(2) : BlueButton2.gotoAndStop(1)

  if (event.keyCode==81)
  (!played3)?played3 = true : played3 = false;
  (played3)?myChannel3 = mySound3.play() : myChannel3.stop();
  (played3)?BlueButton3.gotoAndStop(2) : BlueButton3.gotoAndStop(1)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function keydown(event:KeyboardEvent):void
{
  if (event.keyCode==192) {
     (!played2)?played2 = true : played2 = false;
     (played2)?myChannel2 = mySound2.play(0,100) : myChannel2.stop();
     (played2)?BlueButton2.gotoAndStop(2) : BlueButton2.gotoAndStop(1)
  }

  if (event.keyCode==81) {
     (!played3)?played3 = true : played3 = false;
     (played3)?myChannel3 = mySound3.play() : myChannel3.stop();
     (played3)?BlueButton3.gotoAndStop(2) : BlueButton3.gotoAndStop(1)
   }
}
```

Because in your case:

```
if (event.keyCode==192)
(!played2)?played2 = true : played2 = false;
(played2)?myChannel2 = mySound2.play(0,100) : myChannel2.stop();
(played2)?BlueButton2.gotoAndStop(2) : BlueButton2.gotoAndStop(1)
```

If event.keyCode != 192 only line

```
(!played2)?played2 = true : played2 = false;
```

will not be executed, but the other 2 lines will be executed. 
The same for keyCode != 81 condition